# how to add more simple products into configurable products using magento API

Tags: magento

How can I simply add new simple products incrementally to configurable products?

or do I still need to retrieve the 2 original arrays of the pre-defined configurable product (getConfigurableAttributesData and getConfigurableProductsData) first, append the new arrays and set them again? Is it worked for my case just as the first-time creation?

And if the new simple product owns a new attribute / attribute options, do I also need to create /edit the attribute first before adding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The API as it stands does not have the functionality to do this.

Your options are:

1. Extend the API. (Hours of fun)
2. Do it with Magento methods in your own module or standalone code that includes Mage.php.
3. SQL script mixed in with your existing API code.
4. Buy someone's module - ([Hope your German is good](http://www.netzkollektiv.com/produkte/magento-extensions/netzkollektiv-api-extension-fur-magento-core-api/))

The approach you take also depends on your SKU naming scheme, if you have a simple BASECODE-SIZE-COLOUR type of scheme then the SQL option can work a treat, and in next to no time, but will be heavily scorned on by Magento evangelists.

That means you are probably going to have to write your own code. Here is a very useful site that should help get you started:

http://www.ayasoftware.com/

As well as being able to import configurables (by a variety of means including SQL) there are also snippets of code useful for updating superattribute price differentials. No readymade complete solution, but, you may need to roll your own anyway depending on your SKU naming scheme.

Whilst you are at it you may also want to write some code to find simple products that are not hooked up to anything when they should be, i,e. the ones with no visibility.